# Mercurial -r option not working as intended when targeting a tag with dashes

Tags: mercurial

I've noticed that the -r option in mercurial behaves a bit unexpectedly while I was building a script to automate the release procedure. The release procedure uses the hg archive -r  but the behavior is the same for hg update -r  ..

I've made a very basic mercurial repository to showcase the behavior:
https://bitbucket.org/daang/mercurial-revision-problem-example

The problem is, when you use the -r option, with a tag that does not exist, and separate the numbers with a dash (-) mercurial will update the revision to the first number in the tag.

So if using the provided repository I do:

```
hg update -r 0-2-2 ( this tag does not exist)
```

Mercurial will update the repository to the initial commit ( revision 0 )

If I do:

```
hg update -r 1-2-2 ( this tag does not exist )
```

It will update to the revision 1

```
hg update -r 5-2-2 ( this tag does not exist )
```

Will update to revision 5

However if I use the tag convention with the dots, it will work as expected and if the tag is provided that does not exist it will throw an error 'empty revision'

```
hg update -r 2.2.2 ( this will not work)
```

Why does mercurial behave like this and when using the tag convention with dashes (1-0-0) it takes only the first number and updates to that revision if the tag does not exist, but with dots (1.0.0) fails when the tag is not found ( which is the correct behavior I presume ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Mercurial cannot interpret the revision as a tag, bookmark, branch, revision number (absolute or relative), or hash, and it isn't one of the special revisions `.`, `tip`, or `null` (see `hg help revisions`) it will try to parse it as a revset (`hg help revsets`). In revset notation, the `-` operator implements set difference, i.e. the revisions on the left hand side except for the revisions on the right hand side. So, for example, `1-2-2` is parsed as `(((1)-2)-2)`, which is the same as revision 1.

You can avoid this interpretation by using explicit revset syntax, for example:

```
hg update -r 'tag("1-2-2")'
```

You can also quote the revision description to avoid interpretation of operators, e.g.:

```
hg update -r '"1-2-2"'
```

Note that you need two levels of quotes because the shell will strip the outer level.

Comment: That does it. Checking the revset documentation confirms it. Initially it's very misleading if you don't know mercurial falls back to revsets, now it makes much more sense.
Thanks :)